# Nodejs function parameters

Tags: node.js

I watched an online tutorial about implementing a RESTful API. It used node js with MySQL database.

I can't understand following function call:

```
app.route('/users/{id}').get(users.readUserId)

readUserId = function(req, res) {
    user.getOneUser(function(result) {
        res.json(result);
    });
};

getOneUser = function(userId, done) {
    db.get().query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user_id = ?', userId, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        done(rows);
    });
};
```

they were in different files (thats why it looks like a nested function call). The thing I don't understand is that the `getOneUser` function takes two arguments. But when `readUserId` calls it, `readUserId` only inserts one argument. How could it work?

Comment: Is this code _exactly_ the way it is in the tutorial you read? Because if it is, it's wrong.

Comment: Yeah, obviously  userId is missing.

Comment: it should be `user.getOneUser(someUserId, function(result){...})`

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I can't find the video any more but I downloaded its source code. I just checked it looks exactly like that

Comment: @chrisgjh probably a typo from the author, should really be `user.getOneUser(req.params.id, function(result) { ... })`. We all have off days :)

Comment: What are `user` and `users`, where do they come from? Are those functions really assigned to global variables?

Comment: @Bergi "*they were in different files*"